Can Jenkins auto add Webhook in Gitlab (with any plugins)?
I have the access token for Gitlab and configured it in Jenkins. I now want to add a task in Jenkins that uses my token and uses the JenkinsFile from my project, is there any way I can configure the webhook without going to gitlab? Can Jenkins use my JenkinsFile, and and any plugins, to automatically create the webhook?
I noticed this paragraph in my Jenkinsfile:
    triggers {
        gitlab(triggerOnPush: true, triggerOnMergeRequest: true, branchFilterType: 'All')
    }

Is this using a plugin that will automatically create the webhook?

When using the GitLab Branch Source Plugin as your source in a Multibranch Pipeline job it will create the needed webhooks automatically in addition to integrating with the Jenkinsfile in your various branches.
